# How do I have a fade animation when switching between tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I am trying to add a subtle fade in/out animation on the content of a tab style menu.  I have tried the jQuery `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`  I could not get it to work without it having some sort of issue with which content was staying displayed or it seemed like the fades seemed at different paces.

I created a fiddle with a simplified version of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/SMpCS/3/

```
$('.room_tab').fadeOut(400, function () {
    $('.room_tab').delay().removeClass('show_tab');
    });

$('#room_tab_' + id).delay(400).fadeIn(400, function () {
    $('#room_tab_' + id).addClass('show_tab');
});
```

This partially worked but when changing tabs the first time it seems too sudden. It is like the fadeOut is not triggering initially.

Another issue is that if the user clicks the already selected tab it runs the fade again which I do not want to happen.

Is their an easier way to accomplish this? Or a way to make this work with the code that is given?

Comment: I don't notice any delay with `.fadeOut()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, only fade out the tab that has `.show_tab`. Also, use `jQuery.prototype.hasClass()` to check that the room with id `"room_tab_"+id` doesn't have `.show_tab`.

```
function updatetab(id){
    var preRoom = $(".room_tab.show_tab");
    var curRoom = $("#room_tab_"+id);
    if (!curRoom.hasClass("show_tab")) {
        preRoom.fadeOut(400, function () {
            preRoom.delay().removeClass('show_tab');
        });

        curRoom.delay(400).fadeIn(400, function () {
            curRoom.addClass('show_tab');
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This worked very well and hit all of the issues that I had.  Thank you!  Should I include this catch in the function `if (!id) {return;}` or is it unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, adding that would be a good idea. You might want to have an array `acceptableIds[]` and then `return false;` immediately if `acceptableIds.indexOf(id) === -1`.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMpCS/6/)**

Add `delay()` to `fadeOut`.

And instead of fading out all tabs, just fade out the active tab `$('.room_tab.show_tab')`

```
$('.room_tab.show_tab').delay(400).fadeOut(400, function () {
    $('.room_tab.show_tab').removeClass('show_tab');
});
```

Comment: The delay is now taken care of with this so thank you!  Now is it possible to disable the animation if the user clicks the tab that is already selected?

Comment: That solved that issue as well.  Thanks again, but this solution has a slight jump effect after the current content has faded the content is fading in below and jumping to the top.  @Noble Mushtak has a solution that solves all of the issues and does not have the jumping, So I am going to accept that answer.  Thank you for the help though!